# Android: How can make custom PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I am trying to create a PreferenceScreen but i want the Activity design like the whole projects.

How can create a custom PreferenceScreen design ?

Comment: Sorry, can you expand your question? Or maybe make it more clean? I think that yours is a design/graphic problem

Comment: ya its, but i want to ask its doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you are searching for.

```
PreferenceScreen screen = createPreferenceHierarchy();
```

..
    `this.setContentView(rootView);` => i think you can set it from xml layout also.

```
setPreferenceScreen(screen);
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's doable. Apologies for the layout, my pasting never seems to keep the right formatting, but content works...

Preferences.java

```
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;

  public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.preference_holder);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);

    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backPrefBurron);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    BTFirstTab.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

     }
  }
```

then a preferences holder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/bto_dark_green" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="4dip">
    <Button android:id="@+id/backPrefBurron" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Home" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/backText" android:textSize="14dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Preferences: Home will update all areas of the app" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/bto_light_green">

<EditTextPreference android:title="Your BTO UserName"
    android:key="username" android:summary="Please provide your username">          </EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference android:title="Your BTO Password"
    android:password="true" android:key="password" android:summary="Please provide your password (case sensitive)"></EditTextPreference>
<ListPreference android:title="Species order"
    android:summary="This preference selects the species order for some viewing sightings activities"
    android:key="speciesorder" android:defaultValue="date_order" android:entries="@array/listArray"
    android:entryValues="@array/listValues"></ListPreference>
  </PreferenceScreen>
```

This way I have a common header that I use in other pages.

Comment: is this possible when i am using preferenceFragment?